# How to resolve pylance "Series[Unknown]" error for dataframe using applymap

Tags: python, pandas, pylance

I've been running into the following pylance error.

```
Object of type "Series[Unknown]" is not callable
```

Sample code to recreate error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': ['c', 'd', 'e']})
df.applymap(lambda x: 'c' in x) # <-- this is the line which cause the pylance error
```

Note that I am using the following:

- python==3.9.0
- pandas==1.5.3
- pylance (vscode extension)==v2023.12.1

Thank you.

Comment: The error is probably related to the fact that `applymap` is deprecated. My guess is that it's not deprecated in your pandas version but is deprecated in the pandas-stubs version used in pylance. Replace it with something else, perhaps `str.contains`.

Comment: @cottontail, thank you. You are correct and i've since manage to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @cottontail.

He's right to say that applymap is deprecated in the latest pandas version. I can achieve what I want with the following 2 options.

```
df.map(lambda x: 'c' in x).any(axis = 1)
```

or

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('c')).any(axis=1)
```